# Translating username on language Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, display-names, localization

I would like to translate my (user)name to different alphabets/languages on Stack Exchange sites where that's appropriate, like the Russian Stack Exchange and Russian Stack Overflow.

People shouldn't have to switch their keyboard layouts to @ someone.

Comment: From reading the first part of your question, it seemed to me like you were asking specifically about the Community user, while you were actually asking about your own username. Can you make this clear to people who only skim your question?

Comment: As an aside, there's a few users who misuse Unicode chars. Others have usernames in non Latin languages. Translation or transliteration in general would be a project on its own. Renaming community is maybe plausible

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I guess it's two questions. I thought about localizing my own username while writing about the \@Community user.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I split my question into 2 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342006/localize-the-username-of-the-community-user

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is already possible. You aren't required to use the same username on all sites; you can use different usernames on different sites.

Simply enter a different username on a given site's profile editor, and click the translation of "Save changes just for this community". You'll have a different username for that community.

I understand that this is a bit of an issue for the Russian language specifically, since there are two sites in the Russian language (ru.SO and rus.SE; not counting russian.SE since it's technically not a localized site), but that's a bit of an edge case since there's generally only one localized site per language and this is unlikely to change. (This was a bit of a special case since the two sites were originally operated by a different company and became SE sites after SE Inc. acquired that company.)